# Include folder even when files have been excluded

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules to rewrite all url paths and queries to go to index.php as *route*, except the image files. However, If images are inside a specific_folder want them to be routed through index.php as well.

My .htaccess right now looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This allows me to rewrite everything to go to index.php as a *route*, except the image files. However, If images are inside a specific_folder want them to be routed through index.php as well.

I added the following line after the image files extension condition, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /specific_folder/.*$
```

Comment: RewriteConds are joined by an implicit AND, so you are now demanding that what was requested is not and existing file/folder, and not an image, and in the specified folder at the same time. You will need to use the `OR` flag here to join those conditions in a different way.

Comment: The condition checking the suffix for an image format is probably superfluous though - assuming that you only want to exclude _existing_ image files, the `!-f` condition would have that already covered. (Although, if your `specific_folder` contains other files besides images, you might need it for that part again.)